# Method not changing variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm creating a app that will be accessing the user's webcam. I want to the change the error variable to the error message if `navigator.getUserMedia` fails. This should outputting the error message, but instead it's outputting stream. I'm very new to Vue so pardon me if I'm missing something very obvious
my code is as follows

```
<template>
    <div class="">
      <h1 v-if="error === null">
        Stream
      </h1>
      <h1 v-else>
        {{ error }}
      </h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      error: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setUnsupported () {
      this.error = 'Your browser does not support video :('
    }
  },
  ready () {
    this.setUnsupported()


    if (navigator.getUserMedia) {

    } else {
    }
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h1, h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You may want to check the value of this when you are setting the error it may not be what you think it is. It may be creating a new variable error on different scope?

Comment: I tried adding an alert to the method, and it seems like it's not being called at all. I'm so very confused right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Vue 2.0, `ready` has been replaced with `mounted`. Please check the documentation [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#ready-replaced).

```
....
mounted () {
    this.setUnsupported()
}
....
```